# Adding jar in classpath using regexp

Tags: java

I have a question around addition of specific jars from a specific folder.

Scenario:
I have a lib folder which contains a number of jar files. Due to some issue, I have to give preference to a jar file over others.

Refer this issue: http://bugzilla.slf4j.org/show_bug.cgi?id=327

Now am trying to put a specific jar file to be loaded first here log4j-1.2.17.jar

One option is I simply hardcode this in my app script to make sure this jar is always added firstly in the classpath.

**Problem in the approach:**
Since the project is maven based, there is a chance that log4j version changes. And in that cases I am prone to same issue again, as I have to go and change the version in the script too.

Other option (for which I am searching the solution), there is some possibility like:

Example command (**Expected, but this is not working though**):

```
java -cp <path to my app>/lib/log4j*:<path to my app>/lib/* MainClass
```

The advantage I see here, even if log4j version changes, I will not have to change the script.

Need inputs how can I achieve approach 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

> Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character *, which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. For example, the class path entry foo/* specifies all JAR files in the directory named foo. A classpath entry consisting simply of * expands to a list of all the jar files in the current directory.

So "*" is equivalent to all *.jar files in a directory. Maybe you could put the log4j in a lib/log directory? The following is working for me under Windows:

```
java -cp "lib\*;lib\log\*" MainClass
```

Comment: This is a solution which I have implemented. If you look at my question, I was not looking for sub-directory rather same directory from where just load log4j jar first on classpath, then rest of jars. But I guess there is nothing possible like that.

Comment: Seems like this is the only way out.